# Youtube API with Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube-api

I have a flash banner with a youtube video embeded within it. When the user presses a button, the banner goes to a specific frame and plays the video. What I need it to do, is after the video is finished, for it to forward to another frame.

The AS3 I am using to pull in the youtube video is below:

```
stop();

var player:Object;

Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");

var vidctn:Loader = new Loader();
vidctn.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));
vidctn.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);

function onLoaderInit(e:Event):void{
addChild(vidctn);
player = vidctn.content;
player.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
}

function onPlayerReady(e:Event):void{
player.destroy();
addChildAt(vidctn,0);
player.setSize(304,173);
player.x = 0;
player.y = 40;
player.mute();
player.loadVideoById("Dzz6lUsF19g",0,"large");
}
```

I'm thinking I need an eventlistener, possibly Event.COMPLETE, but I can't seem to come up with one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these are the states of the youtube api (you only need YT_ENDED, but it is nice to have all):

```
        public static var YT_UNSTARTED:int = -1;
        public static var YT_ENDED:int = 0;
        public static var YT_PLAYING:int = 1;
        public static var YT_PAUSED:int = 2;
        public static var YT_BUFFERING:int = 3;
        public static var YT_CUED:int = 5;
```

add a listener:

```
        vidctn.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener("onStateChange", onPlayerStateChange);
```

and here is the function:

```
        protected function onPlayerStateChange(event:Event):void {
            trace("youtubePlayer: player state:", Object(event).data);
            if(Object(event).data==YT_ENDED) {
                   //here you can do your stuff
            }
       }
```